# Python tokenizing text: How do I turn a tokenized list into a string?

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I'm trying to tokenize text

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize 

text = '''The team used archive "data" from 2016...and 2017 
captured by the ESA/NASA Hubble Space Telescope and developed 
open-source algorithms to analyse the starlight filtered through 
K2-18b’s atmosphere. The results revealed the molecular 
signature of water vapour, also indicating the presence of 
hydrogen and helium in the planet’s atmosphere.'''

token = (sent_tokenize(text))
token
```

This gives me

```
['The team used archive "data" from 2016...and 2017 captured by the ESA/NASA Hubble Space Telescope and developed open-source algorithms to analyse the starlight filtered through K2-18b’s atmosphere.',
 'The results revealed the molecular signature of water vapour, also indicating the presence of hydrogen and helium in the planet’s atmosphere.']
```

How do I turn this into a string, but keep the  ' ' around each sentence?

Anything I've found concatenates the elements in the list and takes away the tokenization.

**EDIT:** I essentially want this output below. When being parsed, will python treat the `.\n` as a new line? (Note I got this form of tokenization from the readability python [page](https://pypi.org/project/readability/)

```
text = ('This is sentence one .\n' 
'This is sentence two \n.')
```

Thanks

Comment: The `sent_tokenize(text)` call _is_ returning a list of strings. The example you gave of `text = ('sent 1' 'sent 2')` will concatenate them without the quote characters, which is what you said you _don't_ want. Can you edit your question to be clearer about the output you're looking for?

Comment: OP can you clarify what you want? `text = ('This ....` doesn't really say much. Is that a string with a newline character after every quoted sentence or what? Or is it, as @damon said; you are trying to concatenate them in the end?

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear. I actually want `.\n`  after each sentence, as per the tokenized text on the readability python package. When python is parsing this string, does it recognise `.\n` as a new line? https://pypi.org/project/readability/

Comment: @cget , you can try it out with: `print('first sent.\nsecond sent.')`. The quick answer is yes, each sentence will print to a row.

Answer (score 1):

Working off of the info you currently have in your OP, you can try this:

```
a = ['sentence 1', 'sentence 2', 'let me guess... a third sentence?']

s = str(a).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(', ', '\n').replace(',', '\n')
print(s)
```

This will output:

```
$ python p.py
'sentence 1'
'sentence 2'
'let me guess... a third sentence?'
```

Note the use of `replace(', ', '\n')` and `replace(',', '\n')`.